hamburger menu navbar responsive

I am getting issue with X when the hamburger menu is activated.
The "X" is not showing symmetrical.
Can someone have a look and explain what i am doing wrong.
I have added down the CSS styling.
Thanks in advance!

hamburgerMenu > X
See CSS styling.
CSS styling as PNG

Please add enough code to create a [mre]. Furthermore please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you have to play with the translate(X,Y) numbers at the end of your CSS
open the inspector (right click inspect) and find the right number by playing in the css tab on the right
exemple (not tested)
.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1){
 transform:rotate(45deg) translate(5px,8px); /* e.g */
}
.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3){
 transform:rotate(45deg) translate(5px,8px); /* e.g */
}

